# OIDC - Getting "Unable to unprotect the message.State" + "message.State is null or empty" but only sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have OIDC client where our users sometimes gets 2 errors. I have dataprotection enabled. I'm running behind an AWS loadbalancer but with only 1 target.

Most of our users are able to login just fine.

Client setup code:

```
services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = Coo
                })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/login";
                    options.Cookie.Name = PrepareWebCookieNames.AuthCookie;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1); // TODO: Config
                    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = siteSettings.ReaderAppClientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = siteSettings.ReaderAppClientSecret;

                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;

                    options.Authority = _oidcSettings.Authority;

                    options.Scope.Add(WellKnownScopes.SsoApiManageScope);
                    options.Scope.Add(WellKnownScopes.SsoApiProfileScope);
                    options.Scope.Add(WellKnownScopes.PrepareApiScope);

                    options.MapInboundClaims = false;

                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

                    options.EventsType = typeof(MvcOpenIdConnectEvents);
                });
```

...

```
        services.AddAntiforgery(opts => opts.Cookie.Name = PrepareWebCookieNames.AntiForgery);

        services
            .AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("PrepareWeb")
            .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(cacheAccessConnectionManager.TempStoreConnection);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Sometimes"?  Do some users always work and other never work.  Or do you mean some users get the error occasionally?

Comment: For some users it always works. For other users they get the error occasionally but are able to login just fine most of the time.

Comment: When you logon a request is made to a password server to verify user.  On some systems there will be a delay and a timeout will occur if the delay is too long giving the error.  Adding a retry when fail may help.

Comment: I'm in control of the identity server, so if there is something that can be done on there i'm open for it. But you mean I should catch the exception and redirect to logon again? Or what do you mean by "retry"?

Comment: It is a timeout issue.  Sometimes the identity server is not responding quick enough (possibly do to load issues or network errors).  I assume you mean get credentials when you say login.  So yes you may need to get credentials again.